# 0-5V Audio Signal with TL082

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, audio, voltage-divider

I am working on an Arduino project that requires me to be able to handle audio input from a 1/4" input jack, and it needs to be powered with just one 9V DC input. Since the Arduino cannot process negative voltages, my input needs to be centered around 2.5V, not 0V. I found the attached schematic on a similar question, but it uses an LM321, and I only have a TL082. I'm new to op amps, so I don't know much about the differences between them, and I'd rather be as cautious as possible with my components. Therefore, my question is:

**Will this schematic also work with a TL082 in the place of the LM321, and if not, how else can I achieve a 0-5V audio signal with a singly-powered TL082?**

[image: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/156565/convert-an-audio-signal-to-0-5v-using-single-supply-op-amp]

Cited question: [Convert an audio signal to 0-5V using single supply op amp](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/156565/convert-an-audio-signal-to-0-5v-using-single-supply-op-amp)

TL082 Datasheet from TI: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl082-n.pdf

Comment: Please provide a link to the manufacturer's datasheet for the op amp you want to use.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Sorry about that; I've updated the question with a link to the datasheet

Comment: The TL082 does not look like a good choice. You need an op amp that is specified with an input and output voltage range that goes all the way to the negative supply voltage. Look for something that is specified to work with a single supply.

Comment: The TL082 output will not swing as low as ground. You might get  a minimum of 1.5 volts above ground then it will clip.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, everyone. From what you're all saying it looks like my best option is to just invest in another op amp. Is the LM321 my best option?

Comment: Sorry, we don't recommend specific products on this site. In any event, you are the only one who knows what "best" means to you.

Comment: LM321 can swing closer to GND at the output than the TL082 but still not all the way to GND, Swing toward VCC for LM321 is not much better than the TL082. There are many choices available for low power opamps that support what is called "rail to rail inputs" and "rail to rail outputs". Try searching for those.